# Binary output as text in the browser

Tags: browser, binary, output

I have a problem with a script whose purpose is to send a file to be downloaded to the browser.
Locally, everything goes well, but when the script runs on the server, instead of downloading the content (binary) is displayed as text in the browser.
I checked the apache configurations locally and on the server, they are substantially identical...
Can you enlighten me on this problem?

Thank you in advance for your response.

[edit] It's a Symfony 1.4 website using sfWebRequest->setContentType() to set the response 'Content-type' header. When testing on localhost, the header 'Content-type' is correctly set to the value configured in the code. When testing on the server, the header 'Content-type' is always set by the server to 'text/html', displaying textual content in the browser.

Comment: Can you check what are the mime types sent locally and from the server?

Comment: I put some more details in the description